# PostgreSQL 9.5: Logging exception handling

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following function for handling exception.

```
create or replace function fun_test(a varchar) returns void as
$$
begin

insert into test values(a);

exception when others
then
raise info '%',SQLSTATE;

end;
$$
```

The above function gives me the output:

**OUTPUT**:

```
INFO: 42804
```

**Note**: I want to record the same output in the *.log file.

Comment: it very much depends on where you want it - if in postgres log, then just raise warning and change posgtres.conf to log warnings, if you want in other file on the server, you can use `COPY`, but it won't append to file, etc... please give us details - what exactly you wont, not just `*.log`

Comment: I want it in postgres log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html)

> `log_min_messages` (enum) Controls which message levels are written to
>   the server log. Valid values are DEBUG5, DEBUG4, DEBUG3, DEBUG2,
>   DEBUG1, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, ERROR, LOG, FATAL, and PANIC. Each
>   level includes all the levels that follow it. The later the level, the
>   fewer messages are sent to the log. The default is WARNING. Note that
>   LOG has a different rank here than in client_min_messages. Only
>   superusers can change this setting.

If you set it to INFO, your raise output will appear in postgres logs